# What are the two recursive calls in MergeSort?

Tags: performance, algorithm, mergesort

Studying Algorithms and having some difficulty understanding what specifically constitute the two recursive calls in MergeSort. Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Consider showing the pseudo code you're working with. I guess you're referring to the left list + the right list being merged recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the array be of size **N**. Basically take the array and divide into two parts form 1 to **N/2** and **N/2 + 1** to **N**. Let us call these parts **L** and **R** respectively. Now if we can sort **L** 
and **R** separately we can just merge them to get the final result. Now how do you sort **L** and **R**
, well again apply the same procedure. Thus comes two recursive parts, one to sort recursively **L**
and oe two recursively sort **R** after which they are merged. Th pseudo code

```
      merge_sort ( 1 , N )
         merge_sort(1,N/2) /* L */
         merger_sort(N/2 + 1,N) /* R */
         merge both these sorted parts
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same thing with only one function.
Here is pseudocode:

```
def mergesort(int l, int r) {

  if l == r:
    return

  int mid = (l + r) / 2
  mergesort(l, mid)
  mergesort(mid + 1, r)

  merge left subarray and right subarray
}
```

Here is C++ code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
const int N = 1000003;

int tmp[N];
int a[N];

void merge_sort(int b, int e) {

  if(b == e) // if there is only one element, then we have an sorted subarray
    return;

  int mid = (b + e) / 2;
  merge_sort(b, mid); //recursive call
  merge_sort(mid + 1, e); //recursive call

  int sz = e - b + 1; // the size of the subarray

  for(int k = 0, i = b, j = mid + 1; k < sz; ++k) {

    if(i > mid) //if we have passed the border of left subarray, use the right one
      tmp[k] = a[j++];
    else if(j > e) // if we have passed the border of right subarray, use the left one
      tmp[k] = a[i++];
    else { // if all borders are oke
      if(a[i] > a[j]) // compare values in left and right subarray
        tmp[k] = a[j++];
      else
        tmp[k] = a[i++];
    }
  }  

  // sorted values form b to e are in tmp array, now just copy the tmp array to array a
  for(int i = 0, j = b; i < sz; ++i, ++j)
    a[j] = tmp[i]; 

}

int main() {

  int n; scanf("%d", &n);
  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);

  merge_sort(0, n - 1);

  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    printf("%d ", a[i]);

  return 0;
}
```